# Logit transformation and smooth term in additive model

Tags: generalized-additive-model

Let the response $y \in (0,1)$, and consider the model via gam
$$ \text{gam}(\text{logit} (y) \sim s(x))$$
where $s$ is a smoother.

Then, gam estimates both $s$, and a coefficient. In my case, the coefficient is equal to $-0.8$.

But then, if we want everything in terms of $y$, we have

$$\text{logit}(y) \approx -0.8s(x) \\\Rightarrow y \approx \frac{e^{y s(x)}}{e^{y s(x)} + 1}$$

Is there any way to display that particular function using gam?

Comment: The problem is different in every language..

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is just a binomial GLM with the logit link function, assuming you represent the smooth $s$ by a set of basis functions. If you want to estimate the wiggliness of $s$ rather than state this up-front, then you can fit the model using penalised likelihood, where the penalty controlling the wiggliness of $s$ is based on the second derivative of the fitted spline.

I would write the model more like

$$\text{logit}(E(y)) = \beta_0 + s(x_i)$$

The bit on the right hand side is the linear predictor and it is on the logit (log odds) scale. Also note we are modelling the expectation of the response not the response itself, which in this case means we are modelling the probability that a trial is successful (i.e. that $y = 1$).

To get the fitted probability for a value of $x_i$, we can rearrange the equation as follows

$$E(y) = \text{invlogit}(\beta_0 + s(x_i))$$

where $\text{invlogit}$ is the *inverse* of the logit function.

As for implementations of this in a GAM framework, there is the original approach of Hastie and Tibshirani using their backfitting algorithm, where the user is required to state how wiggly the function $s$ should be. This is available in, for example, the R package **gam**.

The penalised spline version, where you fit the same binomial GAM but also perform smoothness selection to determine the wiggliness of $s$, is available in Simon Wood's **mgcv** R package, for example.